# Get data from HTML child class

Tags: c#, html

I’m attempting to create a tool, in C#, which gathers and analyses data from a web page/form. There are basically 2 different types of data. Data entered by a user and data created by the system (I don’t have access to).

The data created by the user is kept in fields and the form uses IDs - so GetElementByID is used.
The problem I’m running into is obtaining the data created by the system. It shows on the form, but isn’t associated to an ID.  I may be reading/interpreting the HTML incorrectly, but it appears to be a child class (I don’t have much HTML experience). I’m attempting to get the “Date Submitted” data (near the bottom of the code). Sample of the HTML code:

```
<div class="bottomSpace">
    <div class="importfromanotherorder">
        <div class="level2Panel" >

           <div class="left">
                <span id="if error" class="error"></span>
             </div>

           <div class="right">
                Enter Submission ID
                <input name="Submission$ID" type="text" id="Submission_ID" class="textbox" />
                <input type="submit" name="SumbitButton" value="Import" id="SubmitButton" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bottomSpace">
    <div class="detailsinfo">
        <div class="level2Panel" >

        <div class="left">
                <h5>Product ID</h5>
                1234567
                <h5>Sub ID</h5>
                Not available
                <h5>Product Type</h5>
                Type 1
        </div>

        <div class="right">
                <h5>Order Number</h5>
                0987654
              <h5>Status</h5>
                Ordered
                <h5>Date Submitted</h5>
                7 17 2012 5 45 09 AM
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using GetElementsByTagName (searching for “div”) and then using GetAttribute(“className”) (searching for “right”) generates some results, but as there are 2 “right” classes, it’s not working as intended.

I’ve tried searching by className = “detailsinfo”, which I can find, but I’m not sure how I could go about getting down to the “right” class. I tried sibling and children, but the results don't appear to be working. The next possible problem is that it appears the date data is actually text belonging to class “right” and not element  “Date Submitted” .

So basically, I'm curious as to how the best approach would be to get the data I'm looking for. Would I need to get all of the class “right” text and then try and extract the date string?

Apologizes if there is too much info or not enough of the required info :) Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added how GetElementsByTagName is called using C#  - per Icarus's comment.

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElementCollection elemColl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");
```

Comment: It's not clear how are you calling `getElementsByTagName` using C#.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it if the 'right' instance you want is the 2nd.  Two approaches given:

The commented-out approach is it's zero based, so uses instance 1.
  The second approach is xpath and is therefore one-based so uses instance 2.

```
private string ReadHTML(string html)
{

  System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(html);
  System.Xml.XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;

  //This commented-out approach works and might be preferred if you want to iterate
  //over a node set instead of choosing just one node
  //string key = "//div[@class='right']";
  //System.Xml.XmlNodeList setting = element.SelectNodes(key);
  //return setting[1].LastChild.InnerText;

  // This xpath appraoch will let you select exactly one node:
  string key = "((//div[@class='right'])[2])/child::text()[last()]";
  System.Xml.XmlNode setting = element.SelectSingleNode(key);
  return setting.InnerText;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tom_yes_tom! Unfortunately, as pointed out by Icarus, I wasn't very clear on how I was calling getElementsByTagName. Perhaps 'form' was the incorrect terminology ('form' is the term we use for the page at work). The data is housed solely within a web page (HTML) . To use your code, it expects XML - yes, I tried with HTML, but the X and HT just don't get along :). Although I must say, it appears there are far better data gather methods for XML than HTML.

Comment: Ah.  too bad.  In that case, it would be best if you supplied the full html.  If the html is also well-formed xml, the above would still work.  And if not, if you can grab the snippet you included here and just wrap it with <html><body>your divs</body></html> and it will work.  Sometimes just a little bit of tweaking can take the html and make it valid xml.  (and sometimes not)